# How to pass loop paramters from JSP to Spring Controller

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-boot

I am having a loop on my JSP page and want to pass these values in my Spring Controller. On every click on Retry button in JSP, I need all values in my controller for further processing. The code which I tried so far is:
Any help much appreciated.

JSP File

```
<table class="gridtable">
<tr>
    <th>Queue Name</th>
    <th>Retry Attempt</th>
    <th>Reason for failure</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<% int i=0; %>
<c:forEach var="queueRowDetail" items="${queueRowDetailList}">
<tr>
    <td>${queueRowDetail.queueName}</td>
    <td>${queueRowDetail.attempt}</td>
    <td>${queueRowDetail.errorDetails}</td>
    <td>
        <form:form  method="post"  action="/retry" id="frmFailure_<%=i%>" modelAttribute="queueRowDetail"/>
            <form:hidden path="queueName<%=i %>" value="${queueRowDetail.queueName}"/>
            <form:hidden path="attempt<%=i %>" value="${queueRowDetail.attempt}"/>
            <form:hidden path="errorDetails<%=i %>" value="${queueRowDetail.errorDetails}   "/>

            <input type="button"  value="Retry" onClick="sendobj(<%=i%>)" />
        </form>
    </td>

</tr>
<%  i++; %>
</c:forEach>
```

function sendObj()

```
<script>
    function sendobj(i)
    {
        var x = document.getElementById("frmFailure_"+i);
        alert(obj);
        alert("frmFailure_"+i);
        x.submit();// Form submission

    }
</script>
```

QueueRowDetail Class

```
package com.gartner.gqueuefailureapi.model;
public class QueueRowDetail {

private String queueName;
private String errorDetails;
private int attempt;
private Object payLoad;

public String getQueueName() {
    return queueName;
}
public void setQueueName(String queueName) {
    this.queueName = queueName;
}
public String getErrorDetails() {
    return errorDetails;
}
public void setErrorDetails(String errorDetails) {
    this.errorDetails = errorDetails;
}
public int getAttempt() {
    return attempt;
}
public void setAttempt(int attempt) {
    this.attempt = attempt;
}
public Object getPayLoad() {
    return payLoad;
}
public void setPayLoad(Object payLoad) {
    this.payLoad = payLoad;
}
}
```

InderController.Java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String retryMessage( @ModelAttribute("queueRowDetail")QueueRowDetail queueRowDetail,  ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("queuename", queueRowDetail.getQueueName());
    return "success";

}
```